# How to return a pointer of a class member from a function

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have created class called `Room`as follows

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H
#include <string>

class Room
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    Room* south;
    Room* north;
    Room* east;
    Room* west;
public:

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    Room();
    Room(std::string name, std::string desc);

    //METHODS
    std::string getName();
    std::string getDescription();
    void link(Room *r, std::string direction);
    Room *getLinked(std::string direction);
    void printLinked();

    ~Room();


};

#endif // ROOM_H
```

/*************************************************************************/

```
void Room::link(Room *r, std::string direction)
{

    if (direction == "south")//THIS IS JUST FOR TEST
    {
        this->south = this->getName();
    }
}
/*************************************************/
Room Room::*getLinked(std::string direction)
{
    return south;
}
```

And here is my question in `getLinked` method how can I return the pointer (e.g. `south`,`north`,`east`,`west`)

Comment: The correct syntax would be `Room* Room::getLinked(std::string direction)`.

Comment: Can you try to trim your question down to a [MCVE] that rproduces your problem please?

Comment: Consider using `const std::string& direction` as your parameters to avoid unnecessary copying of the strings.

Comment: Good to use a reference, but the compiler will optimize it out anyway.

Comment: Also consider using an enum for directions, to guarantee that someone can't try to pass, for example, `"cheese"` as a direction.  This would let you use a nice, clean `switch` for each function's body, making them easy to read and maintain.

Comment: @Steeve Thanks a lot it's now working, but can I ask what is the difference between `std::string direction` and `const std::string& direction`

Comment: @JustinTime Awesome, that would be a great idea as well. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Also, in `Room::link()`, you should probably change `this->south = this->getName();` to `this->south = r;`.  The former tries to assign a `std::string` to a `Room*`, which won't compile.

Comment: You're welcome.  And the difference between `std::string direction` and `const std::string& direction` is that the former is a new string, while the latter is a [reference to a pre-existing string (that doesn't let you change the string)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)#Uses_of_references) (scroll down to the end of that section).  When you use the former as a function parameter, then whatever string you pass will be copied; when you use the latter, you'll just use the original string.  Semantically, it's just a new name for a variable that exists somewhere else.

Comment: @JustinTime I got it now, thanks again for that reference

Comment: That's good.  You're welcome, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually asking what's the correct definition syntax for the `Room::getLinked()` function is?

Well, here you go:

```
Room* Room::getLinked(std::string direction) {
    if(direction == "south") {
        return south;
    }
    // ... the other directions
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I was getting errors with my code, and I forgot totally to look at method syntax. Thanks your answer helped a lot